# Optimizing 'Most Recent Month' query for View

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-view

I currently have a join query I'm using to build a view that returns only those records created within the most recent month, as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MostRecentMonth] AS
SELECT <fields>
FROM dbo.CensusFile
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(CENSUS_MONTH) as MAXMONTH FROM dbo.CensusFile
)
AS child ON (dbo.CensusFile.CENSUS_MONTH = child.MAXMONTH)
GO
```

The query is returning the results I expect, but was looking for a more optimal way of building the query to run more efficiently on what is a large dataset. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: For which DBMS are you asking this? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? … From the non-standard name delimiters, dbo and GO, I guess it's SQL Server?

Comment: sorry...should have been specific. yes to SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability I would move the criteria to the `WHERE` clause where it belongs:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MostRecentMonth AS
SELECT <fields>
FROM dbo.CensusFile
WHERE census_month = (SELECT MAX(census_month) FROM dbo.CensusFile);
```

Another option would be a window function, but I don't think it would be faster and it's even less readable.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MostRecentMonth AS
SELECT <fields>
FROM
(
  SELECT <fields>, MAX(census_month) OVER () AS maxmonth
  FROM dbo.CensusFile
) with_maxmonth
WHERE census_month = maxmonth;
```

Most important for either query is that you have an index on `census_month`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON MostRecentMonth(census_month);
```

Comment: really helpful...i should have considered indexing census_month. thanks for the catch!